# Yarn: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm trying to migrate from npm to Yarn. When I tried to install dependencies through yarn, I'm getting this error.

```
unable to verify the first certificate
at Error (native)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1055:38)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:580:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:412:38)
```

Same works fine with npm. Tried setting proxy, didn't help.Is there any configuration I need to change?

Comment: Could you provide more details like 
1. When did you encounter this error? Was it at `yarn install`?
2. What is the complete stack trace? Which npm package threw this error?

Answer (score 128):

If the certificate is unable to be verfied, you can open set strict-ssl to false.  You should be able to configure this by runnning

`yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g`

But the command is currently not working, see [issue 980](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/980).

As an alternative you can navigate to C:\Users\\ and open `.yarnrc` and manually update it as follows:

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1
strict-ssl false
```

Comment: "If you don't have the certificate available" --- what does this statement even mean?

Comment: Edited for clarification.

Comment: `yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g` worked fine for me. Thanks

Comment: "Manually edit the file that says not to manually edit it" . Probably good to say why that is worth doing....

Comment: You should probably mention that turning off strict-ssl could potentially open you up to man in the middle attacks unless your behind a tusted proxy.  At the very least I'd suggest removing the -g so you set that setting only for yourself rather then forcing it on other users who may not know their ssl isn't secure any more.

Answer (score 47):

This means that more than likely you're behind a corporate proxy that uses a self signed certificate. I'm using version `v0.16.1`, and you can fix this by providing the public certificate to the yarn configuration like so:

```
yarn config set cafile <path-to-certificate.pem>
```

Comment: This ended up working great for me, my one hangup was that I was using Docker so I needed to make sure to add the apk ca-certificates and copy the certs to the docker directory using my dockerfile config first. The SO answer (second ranked) helped with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates. From there it was adding the command you specified.

Answer (score 4):

For Yarn 2 and 3 you can add the following to your `.yarnrc.yml` file

`enableStrictSsl: false`

[More Info in the Docs](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#enableStrictSsl)

Answer (score 4):

All security issues aside (Do not dismiss them lightly !!!)

the command for yarn 3 is :

`yarn config set enableStrictSsl false`

Answer (score -2):

I had this error when trying to install the [React Devtools Extensions](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions) behind a corporate proxy with correct certificates setup locally. The yarn.lock file contains many references to https://registry.yarnkpg.com which was bypassing our corporate Nexus.

I was able to install by running:

```
yarn install --no-lockfile
```