# ASP.NET Core HttpClient can't make HTTPS calls in container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I am in the process of migrating an API from Windows .NET Full Framework (4.6.1) to ASP.NET Core.

I was able to spin up a container in our Rancher environment via the following Dockerfile:

```
root@a84db3bdc3cf:/app# cat Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY $source .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

I have noticed that anyone in my code that uses `HttpClient` that makes a call to a `HTTPS` url, the call fails.

The `Message` in the `InnerException` reads:

> SSL connect error

Has anyone seen this, and if so, do you know if there is some extra configuration required for the container to be able to do HTTP operations via HTTPS?  It seems to work fine with HTTP.

**EDIT:**

My application doesn't run over HTTPS.  It is hosted over HTTP.  The code in my application is trying to make a call to a remote API that is hosted over HTTPS, and has a valid certificate.

Comment: Could it be related to your docker image not having `ca-certificates` installed? [This resource](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/docker-for-dotnet-developers-part-5) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net core on linux uses curl to provide the implementation of HttpClient

you can test if that's working for you like this

```
docker run  microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 curl https://server
```

and if it doesn't, try this to see if you have the same problem as I did:

```
docker run  microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 curl -k https://server
```

For me, the problem was that part of the certificate chain was missing from the cert store for the site I was connecting to.

I modified the Dockerfile like so:

```
# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

COPY missing-cert.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates
RUN echo missing-cert.crt >> /etc/ca-certificates.conf
RUN update-ca-certificates

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myaspdotnetapp.dll"]
```

And it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to expose `443` instead of `80`  as the 443 is the default port for `Https`

```
root@a84db3bdc3cf:/app# cat Dockerfile
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
COPY $source .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

But Note that you should be sure that your docker contains a certificate 
[docker container ssl certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates)

Comment: I want to clarify here.  My app doesn't run over HTTPS.  However, the code of my app makes an API call to another site that is hosted over HTTPS.

Comment: have you make a check if the api you want to call support Https