# How to use the certificate on the host from the windows container?

Tags: docker, authentication, certificate, containers

I am wondering that is there any good way to import the certificate to container from the host(**certificate is not built-in the image**)? Any solution for both *Linux* and *Windows* container?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates) is a possible solution for *Linux* container/host from other's post I have found.

> *P.S. The certificate is not with the code. I don't think it is a good idea to put the certificate with the code, especially the private key. Although, the certificate could be installed to image via docker build flow in this case.*

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple ways to do so.
1. In case you are deploying your docker image to Kubernetes, you can use Secret
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
2. Otherwise, you can try other keys/secrets management services such as Azure KeyVault.