# Dockerfile for Docker hub- including repo files (ssl certs) in commands

Tags: docker

I'm trying to add SSL support to my custom docker image. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-yttrium

# Switch to root user
USER root

# Add SSL support for stripe
# https://docs.lando.dev/config/security.html#certificates
RUN cp lndo.site.pem lndo.site.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

However, this causes the build to fail:

```
Step 4/5 : RUN cp lndo.site.pem lndo.site.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
---> Running in 112093a612fe
[91mcp: cannot stat 'lndo.site.pem': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'lndo.site.crt': No such file or directory
```

The files `lndo.site.pem` and `lndo.site.crt` are committed to the same repository as my Dockerfile.

I found [this answer to adding certs to a local docker build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38467061/1209486), but I am trying to do the same thing for Docker Hub, so my question is different.

What is the path for the files in the repo for use in the Dockerfile?

Structure of my Github repo that I am using to build the image on Docker Hub:

```
  - Dockerfile
  - README.md
  - lndo.site.crt
  - lndo.site.pem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about that files lndo.site.pem and lndo.site.crt is exist on that directory?

On your Dockerfile I see a command:

```
RUN cp lndo.site.pm lndo.site.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

You are looking for file **lndo.site.pem** but on your Dockerfile there is a missing character maybe

```
lndo.site.pm -> lndo.site.pem
```

I think you should sure about that you are copying the certificate files to your container image(on your Dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that typo, but I'm still getting the same error.  I added some more info about the structure of my Github repo to the question.  The problem is that I don't know which path to use for the files in my Github repo in the Dockerfile.

Comment: OK then I suggest you to add this command to your Dockerfile above of `RUN cp lndo.site.pem lndo.site.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates` command.
`COPY lndo.site.crt lndo.site.pem ./`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ezileli's comment, I was able to find the solution:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-yttrium

# Switch to root user
USER root

# Add SSL support for stripe
# https://docs.lando.dev/config/security.html#certificates
COPY lndo.site.pem lndo.site.crt /certs
RUN update-ca-certificates
```