# Api calls made from fargate container needs to be validated against a certificate. Where can I put the certificates in this scenario?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Api calls made from fargate container needs to be validated against a certificate. Where can I put the certificates. Can it be placed inside the container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker container ssl certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an API Gateway, you can use the API Gateway to generate an SSL certificate and then use its public key in the backend to verify that HTTP requests to your backend system are from API Gateway

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html