# error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib

Tags: linux, docker, ssl, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API hosted in Kubernetes as a Pod. It is also exposed as a Service.
I have created a Dev SSL certificate and it's produced a aspnetapp.pfx file.

Here is a snippet of my Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password={password}
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=APIGateway/Certificates/aspnetapp.pfx
```

When I run the app in Kubernetes I receive an error in the container logs, and the container is failing to start:

```
error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib
```

I know its able to find the SSL certificate but, its throwing the above error.

Please help!:)

Comment: Hello @Sach K, is your error you included a part of something bigger and looks like in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/683637)? Are you using nginx?

Comment: Hi @MikolajGlodziak I am not using nginx. I'm trying to get SSL working in my .NET Core Web API which is hosted in Kubernetes - Docker Desktop installation. I get this error every time I start the container.

Comment: Try to convert your certificate to .crt format. You can also read this page: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/

Comment: I've read the page however this article mentions that I need to pass the file path to the .pfx file. https://dylanbeattie.net/2020/11/18/using-https-with-kestrel.html

Comment: Now I'm stuck on what the path would be when I'm running in the Linux container.

Comment: Try to mount the certs inside the Docker container and then refer to this path: `docker run -v /host/path/to/certs:/container/path/to/certs -d IMAGE_ID "update-ca-certificates"` Like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same problem and even though things were working fine previously, *something* was updated (possibly .NET 6.0.402) which caused a problem.

What I noticed is that my exported dev cert pfx in the Docker container had it's permissions set to:

```
-rw------- 1 root    root    2383 Oct 18 14:40 cert.pfx
```

In my Dockerfile, I export the dotnet dev cert and run a chmod to add read permissions for everyone:

```
RUN dotnet dev-certs https --clean && dotnet dev-certs https --export-path /app/publish/cert.pfx -p {password}
RUN chmod 644 /app/publish/cert.pfx
```

This resulted in permissions which were the same as my appsettings files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     535 Oct 18 14:11 appsettings.Development.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     331 Sep 27 18:13 appsettings.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    2383 Oct 18 14:40 cert.pfx
```

That fixed the error for me.