# POST request - works on local (200), but not on docker (403) - Python3

Tags: python, docker, google-authentication

the python code I tried to work with, simplified the most I could is:

```
import requests
  
params = {
    'Email': 'someaccount@gmail.com',
    'EncryptedPasswd': 'longEncryptedPassword'
}
response = requests.post('https://android.clients.google.com/auth', data=params)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```

Now when I trying to run that code on any of my hosts, it works fine:

```
ᐅ python -VV    
Python 3.7.2 (default, Apr 23 2021, 12:30:59) 
[GCC 10.2.0]                                                                                  
ᐅ python test.py
200
b'SID=BAD_COOKIE\nLSID=BAD_COOKIE\nservices=mail,hist,multilogin,android'                     

---
atay@atay$ ~ ᐅ python3 -VV 
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0]                                                                                   
atay@atay$ ~ ᐅ python3 test.py
200
b'SID=BAD_COOKIE\nLSID=BAD_COOKIE\nservices=mail,hist,multilogin,android' 

---
pi@raspberrypi$ ~ ᐅ python3 -VV      
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0]                                                                                   
pi@raspberrypi$ ~ ᐅ python3 test.py  
200
b'SID=BAD_COOKIE\nLSID=BAD_COOKIE\nservices=mail,hist,multilogin,android'
```

but when trying to run same code on docker I've got error response:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app python:3.7.2 sh -c 'pip install requests && python -VV && python /app/test.py'

...

Python 3.7.2 (default, Mar 27 2019, 08:41:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
403
b'Error=BadAuthentication'
```

What is also not understandable for me - if I use curlify to create curl that IMO should be identical to that call - it returns 403 instead of 200.

Another thing - if I create same request in Postman, it returns 200, but if I export it in Postman to CURL command, it returns 403 again.

I'm not sure what can be the issue in this case, any clues?

Comment: Could that be problem with ssl certificates? Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer myself, as I found the solution, but still do not understand what's wrong.

Looks like pip library `requests>=2.25.0` does not work, but all the earlier version works, so changing code to:

```
ᐅ docker run -v $(pwd):/app python:3.9 sh -c 'pip install requests==2.25.0 && openssl version && python -VV && python /app/test.py'
```

makes it work.
Also OpenSSL must be 1.1.1, that's why I use 3.9, instead of 3.7.2.