# SLL/TLS for Docker-Host or every Container

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate

I have some docker container, where websites are running.
I want to add SSL/TLS encryption to all sites. Because of this I would like to know if only the docker host server needs to have a certificate or do I need to give each container their own?

I looked in the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/) but it seems to add protection to docker as an application.
On [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028971/docker-container-ssl-certificates) I found a way to mount the certificate on the image, but if I change the version of the image I would need to mount it all over again.

Comment: You could run a reverse proxy in front and handle the certification there?

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze a reverse proxy seems like a good solution
could you give me input about this guide https://gist.github.com/dahlsailrunner/679e6dec5fd769f30bce90447ae80081 ?